# How to return hash_plan_value from PLAN_TABLE?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I need to get the hash_plan_value automatically from a query plan in Oracle. 
I know that I can see it when I execute EXPLAIN PLAN for "My Query" and then 
`SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY())` shows me the whole plan.

But my point is that I don't find it in the columns of PLAN_TABLE.
For example I can have COST, CARDINALITY and BYTES using SELECT COST,CARDINALITY, BYTES FROM PLAN_TABLE  is there a way to get the PLAN_HASH_VALUE as well ? I mean since it's displayed it's there but I don't know where.
I hope I was clear enough ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan hash is stored in the OTHER_XML column in one of the PLAN_TABLE rows.

**Sample Plan**

```
explain plan set statement_id = 'TEST3' for select * from dual connect by level <= 10;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2874664061

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(LEVEL<=10)
```

**Query to Extract PLAN_HASH**

```
select extractValue(xmltype(other_xml), '/other_xml/info[@type="plan_hash"]') plan_hash
from plan_table
where other_xml is not null
    and statement_id = 'TEST3';

PLAN_HASH
---------
2874664061
```